# UserInterfaceOnly = True is discarded when opening a file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel+VBA file named "Myfile.xlsm" which needs that `UserInterfaceOnly = True` property so the VBA code can perform many operations without the user being aware.

I did place the following code to set `UserInterfaceOnly = True` property in the Workbook_Open event (also tried in the Workbook_Activate event) of "Myfile.xlsm".

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
Dim WSh As Worksheet 
For Each WSh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
    WSh.Protect Password:="myPWD", UserInterfaceOnly:=True 
    DoEvents 
    If WSh.ProtectionMode = False Then MsgBox "UIFOnly Init Failed on " & WSh.Name & " !!" 
    End If 
Next WSh 
End Sub
```

In some cases the UserInterfaceOnly is not set as expected and I get the "UIFOnly Init Failed on " message at opening "Myfile.xlsm" and as a consequence many other problems later.

EVEN BETTER: I created a new very simple "UnlockUIFOnly.xlsm" file which has the same code in `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`.
If I open "UnlockUIFOnly.xlsm" first, protection works as expected. If I then open "Myfile.xlsm" (keeping "UnlockUIFOnly.xlsm" open) it works as expected.
If I close both files and open ONLY "Myfile.xlsm" it fails again.

I'm running Office 365 (version 2203 Build 16.0.150028.20512) 32 bits with Windows 10.

FURTHER OBSERVATION #1: I copied this not working "MyFile.xlsm" from its original directory to a new one.
When I opened it from its new directory, I got a banner to enable contents, and I answered yes. Then everything went smooth (No UIFOnly Init Failed on " message, no error 1004 ...). I checked some functionalities, so Excel asked whether I wanted to save changes, answered yes, then later if I wanted that document to be a trusted document, answered Yes as well.
At second open, I did not get any banner to enable contents (normal) but the problems were back.

FURTHER OBSERVATION #2: I again copied this not working "MyFile.xlsm" from its original directory to a new one.
When I opened it from its new directory, I got a banner to enable contents, and I answered yes. Then everything went smooth (No UIFOnly Init Failed on " message, no error 1004 ...). I checked some functionalities, so Excel asked whether I wanted to save changes, answered YES, then later if I wanted that document to be a trusted document, answered **no**. All further open tentatives asked to enable contents (answer yes) but were smooth.
It looks like declaring a document as trusted bypasses something or changes in which order events are generated, and has a huge impact on my problem

Comment: If all else fails you can always run some code hooked to the ONLOAD event to make sure it's set.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Like the code shown in the question (which is hooked to the onload event)?

Comment: @Chris Maurer. I did not find any ONLOAD event. Is it different from the WorkBook_Open event in Excel ?